# SBCLからシェルコマンドを使いたい。

Tags: lisp

名前付きパイプを以下の様に使う。
$ mkfifo pipe
$ cat pipe
$ echo "text" > pipe    <<--これは別のプロセスから。
text
これをSBCLからやりたい。

以下は動いた。
* (run-program "/bin/ls" '("-a" "/Users/user") :output T)

でもこれは動かない。
* (run-program "/bin/echo" '("text" ">" "pipe") :output T)

さらにこうしたい。
$ echo $(cat pipe) > pipe2

どう書けばよいのでしょうか。

Comment: リダイレクトはシェルの機能ですので、例えば `(run-program "/bin/sh" '("-c" "echo text > pipe") :output T)` でしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

出力のリダイレクトが目的であれば、`:output`に出力先を指定することになるかと思います。

```
* (run-program "/bin/echo" '("text") :output "pipe" :if-output-exists :append)
```